# Writing a Unity Git Ignore File

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I am new to Subversion with Unity and want to start a little Rpg with two other developers.

I know you can create a Gitignore-File on https://www.gitignore.io/ but i really don't know if just passing in "Unity" is correct.

We use Tortoise Git and just want to work together. Are there any examples we could take? There is no need for special features, just a small project for 3 people ;)

Comment: Subversion and Git are different [Version Control Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

Comment: just get the .gitignore for unity and paste in your root project which contain `.git` folder and everything will be fine, that default name list in .gitignore is a good start since mostly it will conflict each other between every user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is fine. It will ignore all the system files that you do not need in the VC.

Those are not special features, they are basic features that you need to ignore or they will constantly conflict between users.

Comment: We just want to work together :D I do not really know what is needed and what is not. So I just need to take the default Unity-Gitignore and everything is fine? This one here : https://www.gitignore.io/api/unity

Comment: yep, this is one I use as base. Then you start adding things later but this one is fine for any projects.

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` is used list files that may be created in your working directory that you don't want to track in the version control or share between developers (e.g., build products, temporary files created by tests, IDE temporary files, etc).

https://www.gitignore.io/ which you mentioned is a great place to start, but you don't have to limit  yourself to it, and can always add/remove/modify entries in your file as you see fit. For a starting point, you could use the site's generated file for unity and whatever editor you all agree upon. E.g., [unity with vim](https://www.gitignore.io/api/unity%2Cvim).

Comment: Well I just want to develop together and avoid conflicts by the different Editor Layouts. E.g. Merge conflicts etc.